# XSL for converting XML to CSV : Adding Quotes to the end based on data field

Tags: java, xml, xslt, csv

I am trying to convert a XML file to CSV file dynamically using Java code. I am able to obtain the data converted to CSV but the problem is my data is having "" and ','.

Here is my sample XML:

```
<record>
<column name="ID">537316</column>
<column name="TYPE">MANUAL</column>
<column name="SECONDID">546</column>
<column name="INFO">"THIS","IS",FOR,"TEST"</column>
<column name="KEY">345</column>
</record>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

class xmltocsv {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    File stylesheet = new File("C:/testxsl.xsl");
    File xmlSource = new File("C:/test.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        .newTransformer(stylesource);
    Source source = new DOMSource(document);
    Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("c:/output.csv"));
    transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
}
}
```

Here is my XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:param name="fieldNames" select="'yes'" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of  Select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>,</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = last()"><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sample output should be:

```
ID,TYPE,SECONDID,INFO,KEY
"537316","MANUAL","546","THIS"",""IS"",FOR,""TEST""","345"
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
ID,TYPE,SECONDID,INFO,KEY\n
"537316","MANUAL","546",""THIS","IS",FOR,"TEST"","345"
```

The XML I am using is from Database and contains special character(") which is causing unexpected result(As I open the output CSV using MS Excel) in my output CSV.
I need to validate data the for quotes and if there are quotes I has to add extra quotes for getting the desired output.
Could someone please help me with the if condition that I can use in my XSL for validating the string and searching for ("") in the data.

Comment: But the second line should be
537316,MANUAL,546,"""THIS"",""IS"",FOR,""TEST""",345\n. - You are doing this in a rather circumstantial way.

Comment: Thanks Lune. My problem is I am opening this with MS Excel that is leaving blank columns as it reaches the comma that is embedded inside the data.

Comment: Yes you put the second line correct. I need to obtain that using my XSL code can you help me please.

Comment: I can't reproduce your reported result: Putting the XML and XSLT into http://xslttest.appspot.com/ (and same for Java app) only renders anything after (1) changing "<xsl:value-of  Select" to .. select and (2) adding  <xsl:apply-templates/> to the second xsl:template.
Even then, result is:
537316MANUAL546"THIS","IS",FOR,"TEST"345

Comment: I think your expected output should actually be `537316,MANUAL,546,"""THIS"",""IS"",FOR,""TEST""",345`. If a field has a comma in, then the whole field needs to be surrounded in quotes for it to be treated as one field. And if that field already has quotes in, then such quotes need to be made into double-quotes!

Comment: Yes you are correct Tim I made a mistake in the expected output section my apologies.Could you please help me

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? Changing a single quote `"` into a double-quote `""` would be easier to do in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Tim will you be able to explain a littile more about using XSLT 2.0 for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>ID,TYPE,SECONDID,INFO,KEY&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="record/column">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="substitute">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="substitute">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchString">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="replaceString">""</xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,$searchString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$searchString)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$replaceString"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="substitute">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$searchString)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$replaceString"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will produce the following output:

```
ID,TYPE,SECONDID,INFO,KEY
"537316","MANUAL","546","""THIS"",""IS"",FOR,""TEST""","345"
```

which I believe is a correct representation of your input data in CSV format.

Comment: Thanks Michael,But I am not getting the desired output.My problem is my XSL should be totaly dynamic as it should take different kindes of XML data(I mean different fields).In my XSL, Which is dynamic Is it possible to check the data for " and if it exists convert it to "" i think that will be simplest way to solve this problem

Comment: It cannot be "totally dynamic", but you can certainly adapt it so that column names in the header are taken from the actual data. However, this has nothing to do with your question regarding quoting individual fields.

Comment: Thanks Michael I modified a bit and was able to produce the desired output.Thank you:)

Comment: I am updating my code below, it may help someone later reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
class XmlToCsv {
private static void emitHeaders( Node record ){
    NodeList fields = record.getChildNodes();
    String del = "";
    for( int iField = 0; iField < fields.getLength(); iField++ ){
        Node node = fields.item( iField );
        if( ! ( node instanceof Element ) ) continue;
        System.out.print( del );
        System.out.print( ((Element)node).getAttribute("name") );
        del = ",";
    }
    System.out.println();
}
private static void emitData( Node record ){
    NodeList fields = record.getChildNodes();
    String del = "";
    for( int iField = 0; iField < fields.getLength(); iField++ ){
        Node node = fields.item( iField );
        if( ! ( node instanceof Element ) ) continue;
        System.out.print( del );
        String cont = node.getTextContent();
        cont = cont.replaceAll( "\"", "\"\"" );
        System.out.print( '"' + cont + '"' );
        del = ",";
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    File xmlSource = new File("test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);
    Source source = new DOMSource(document);
    Element table = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList records = table.getElementsByTagName("record");
    emitHeaders( records.item( 0 ) );
    for( int iRec = 0; iRec < records.getLength(); iRec++ ){
        emitData( records.item( iRec ) );
    }
}
}
```

It would be even simpler using JAXB.

Comment: Thanks Lune but I has to integrate this with IBM websphere Lombardi Version 7.2 workflow tool.I has to use XSL only so I cant use this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/*">
<xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:param name="fieldNames" select="'yes'" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

    <xsl:call-template name="substitute">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = last()"><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="substitute">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:param name="searchString">"</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="replaceString">""</xsl:param>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,$searchString)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$searchString)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$replaceString"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="substitute">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$searchString)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="searchString" select="$searchString"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replaceString" select="$replaceString"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```