# I want to replace special characters in xml using xsl while converting it to csv

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have tried for commas ',' but want to do it for double quotes '"' also .

```
 <xsl:variable name="status_name" select="translate(status_name,  ',' , ' ')" />
```

I want to do it simultaneously .

If anyone can help me with this .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What do you want to replace the double-quotes with?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If you're trying to produce a .csv result, you only need to escape quotes as double quotes - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995282/xsl-for-converting-xml-to-csv-adding-quotes-to-the-end-based-on-data-field/25003101#25003101

Comment: I am producing a csv with this .my XML file contains comma and doubleqoutes in the tags I want them to replace with space .

Answer (score 1):

In the case of replacing single characters with other single characters, you can still use translate here, although for double-quotes you will need to escape it in the expression

```
<xsl:variable name="status_name" select="translate(status_name, ',&quot;', '  ')" />
```

In this case, the double quote is also being replaced by a space.

Comment: Hi Tim, I want to replace both comma and doubles quotes in the same line .will it be possible ???

Comment: That is what my answer does. It replaces both commas and double quotes in the same line.