# how to replace character '#' with newline in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, newline

I get a string in xml something like `hello world#how r u#blahblah#blah`.
I need to replace each `#` with newline. So in html it should show as

```
hello world
how r u
blahblah
blah
```

I tried `translate`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('hello world#howru#blahblah#blah','#','&#xa;&#xd;')" />
```

It compiles but doesn't work in both IE and FIREFOX.

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="translate('hello#world','#','&#xa;&#xd;')" />

Comment: i TRIED this , doesn't work

Comment: A browser needs `<br/>` to create a new line. You cannot use the `translate()` function for this, you need a recursive named template - see, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995282/xsl-for-converting-xml-to-csv-adding-quotes-to-the-end-based-on-data-field/25003101#25003101

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0,

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$in" regex="#">
  <xsl:matching-substring><br/></xsl:matching-substring>
  <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Comment: No, I am not using XSLT2.0. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: How we fail when working without syntax-directed editors! Now fixed.