# Export html to csv using xslt - Handle comma and special characters

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />
  <xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TR"><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>                  </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="TD">
         <xsl:for-each select="@*[not(name() = 'class' or name() =       'style')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/>      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
               <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>       
        </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using above XSL to convert HTML to CSV but if TD element contains comma it is being treated as separate column,I need to check if TD element data contains comma(,) if yes include data in double quotes.How do I achieve this?

Comment: Actually, you need to check if the cell contains a **quote**, and escape it to double quote if it does -  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995282/xsl-for-converting-xml-to-csv-adding-quotes-to-the-end-based-on-data-field/25003101#25003101

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSL for converting XML to CSV : Adding Quotes to the end based on data field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995282/xsl-for-converting-xml-to-csv-adding-quotes-to-the-end-based-on-data-field)

Comment: BTW, an `xsl:attribute` instruction makes no sense in a stylesheet that outputs text and creates no elements.