# Using XSLT to Convert XML to CSV - Element Names Same, Attributes Different

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

**[EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION]** I have a bit of a tricky issue. I am trying to convert XML data that our system is pushing out to a CSV format. I've searched and searched and it seems to be simple if the elements are different. However, they are not. Here's the response I get when I send my SOAP request to the server:

```
<ArrayOfMemberInformation>
  <MemberInformation Member_Id="1" Cons_Id="234" Last_Updated="2017-02-06T09:39:57" Last_Updated_By_Cons_Id="234" Last_Updated_By_Name="Jane Doe">
    <Column Name="firstname" Value="Jane"/>
    <Column Name="lastname" Value="Doe"/>
    <Column Name="phone" Value="5551234567"/>
  </MemberInformation>
  <MemberInformation Member_Id="7" Cons_Id="789" Last_Updated="2017-03-14T18:33:03" Last_Updated_By_Cons_Id="789" Last_Updated_By_Name="Johnny Smith">
    <Column Name="firstname" Value="Johnny"/>
    <Column Name="lastname" Value="Smith"/>
    <Column Name="phone" Value="5559876543"/>
  </MemberInformation>
</ArrayOfMemberInformation>
```

I'm trying to make the column "names" the column headers and the values to fall in the appropriate column on subsequent rows. This is the XSLT I'm currently working with to try to make this happen:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMemberInformation/MemberInformation">
<xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>,<xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>,<xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I get when trying to run this is:

```
,,,,
```

(just commas, no data)

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
"firstname","lastname","phone"
"Jane","Doe","5551234567"
"Johnny","Smith","5559876543"
```

Where the column "names" are the column headers and the values populate subsequently below.

Thank you in advance for any insight anyone can provide.

Comment: The sample input XML is good to see.  To help you effectively, we'd also need to see a sample of your desired output, whatever XSL code you've got, and a sample of your current actual output.  Please edit your post to add these in, and, if possible, a detailed explanation of where things are going wrong.

Comment: Will there always be only one Member record? Or is that just in this example?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thank you. I've updated it to hopefully provide more insight. Only one member record is just an example. There could be multiple and a varying amount of members per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMemberInformation">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>"firstname","lastname","phone"&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="MemberInformation">
        <!-- data cells -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Column">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes every record has the same `Column`s, in the same order.

---

If you don't want to hardcode the column names, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/ArrayOfMemberInformation">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="MemberInformation[1]/Column">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="MemberInformation">
        <!-- data cells -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Column">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25003101/3016153